# Offline.js doesnt work

Tags: javascript, connection, offline.js

I am using Offline.js to check my Internet connection in a simple web app. The problem is that i receive only the first connection message and then nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Offline.options = {
    checkOnLoad: true,
    interceptRequests: true,
    reconnect: {
        initialDelay: 3
    },
    requests: true,
    game: false
};

console.log(Offline.check());

Offline.on("up",function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
Offline.on("down", function () {
    console.log("disconnected");
});
});
```

Comment: How do you run the file? Locally using file:/// ?

Comment: i include the file in index.jade (my homepage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works fine, unless you run it locally using the `file://` scheme.

The point is that Offline.js makes requests to `/favicon.ico` to the domain, it is currently running on. For the local scheme, requests to itself can yield a security threat. Therefore it is disabled by default.

1. You can start Google Chrome using the `--allow-file-access-from-files` argument to make it work.
2. In Mac or Linux, go into the folder of your files and run `python3 -m http.server`. Then go to `localhost:8000/` in your browser and locate your HTML file.

Using these approaches, the HTML files will be served over HTTP and it can make proper AJAX calls and Offline.js works again.

**In short:** Offline.js does not work in `file://` schemes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the problem is that with this approach, other users need to use google Chrome with "--allow-file-access-from-files". Is there any way to make it works automatically?

Comment: Sadly no. You have to provide a server (locally or in the WWW) or start Google Chrome with the argument. For example Mozilla Firefox does not even provide such an option.